# Node JS Deprecated : Buffer is deprecated. While connecting to SQL Server in API

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have created a REST API in node js to fetch the records from SQL DB.In my local host I'm getting the error:

> (node:308) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the `Buffer.alloc()`, `Buffer.allocUnsafe()`, or `Buffer.from()` methods instead.

But where exactly I can change my `Buffer()` to `Buffer.alloc()`

I have tried using the latest SQL Connection

```
node : 12.2.0
npm  : 6.9.0
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    var sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");



 // connect to your database
 const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    server : "ABC", 
    port : 1433,
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true
      },
    database : "DEMODB"
})

pool.connect().then(() => {
    //simple query
    pool.request().query('select * from tbl_demo').then(recordsets => {
        res.json(recordsets['recordset'])

    })
  })

});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

Comment: Which version of `mssql` are you using exactly? You can check via `npm list mssql`

Comment: @shkaper , mssql - 5.1.0

Comment: It doesn't look like mssql@5.1.0 uses deprecated Buffer constructors. If you're sure it's not in your code, you can try to find the culprit via something like `grep -R '\sBuffer()' .`